# Parsed data display in JTable

Tags: java, swing, parsing, jtable

I am new to Java.  I have to display xml Parsed data parent nodes on JTabbedPane and child nodes in jtable into respective JTabbedPane. For parsing i have used sax parser and all the data was previously displayed in three JTextarea, I have created TabbedPane and displayed hardcoded string as title but i am not able to set Jtable into it with values.

```
public class JTableDisplay {
    public JTableDisplay() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Test Display");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTable table = new JTable();

        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(table);

        panel.add(tableContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTableDisplay();
    }
}
```

This is sample to create JTable after which i have to arrange the parsed data into in.

Comment: Issue is You can't able to set the HEADER or You can't see the Data in Jtable?

Comment: I am not able to see jtable in tabbedpane, data would be secondary.

Comment: without seeing the Single line of code, how can predict the code fro issue?

Comment: Do not hit the back button to edit a post!  Instead use the small 'edit' link below it.  As it is, you wiped out the tidying up I did of the question (which needs it)..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ok Sir will take care of it from now onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is there. It is just not showing any data.

To make your table visible, try defining columns and rows for your table via the constructor :

```
 JTable table = new JTable(3,4);
```

Get it?

Now you just need to define the **tablemodel** and you are set.

Comment: Thank You. how do i display data dynamically into it. I have a parsed XML with three different attributes and i want to display parent nodes in tab and child nodes in jtable is that possible in jtable.

Comment: Of course its possible. Just implement AbstractTableModel to show the child nodes. Dynamically go through the parent nodes, and for each parent, create a tabbed panel, and then get the child nodes in each panel, and set that into your TableModel, and set the table model into the JTable. Just read up on JTables and TableModels.

Comment: Thanks For the guidelines will try it, do u have any references links for the same which i can refer when needed. ThAnKs AgAin

Comment: Depends how you want to display the child nodes. Do you really want to display them in a table? Or would a JTree be better? Or you could even consider a JTreeTable. Are the child nodes all the same level?

Comment: Below is sample of small portion of xml file between quotes is parent node and other than it are child nodes parent nodes needed to be displayed in tabbedpane and childnode in Jtable the purpose behind is child nodes can be edited with correct values and will    again generate back in xml format.

Comment: <Variable Name="Mold1.sv_rMoldStroke">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>6.000000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxSpeedBwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>5.000000e+01</Value>
      </Variable>
      <Variable Name="Core1.sv_rMaxPressureFwd">
         <Typ>REAL</Typ>
         <Value>1.450000e+02</Value>
      </Variable>

Comment: will do accordingly. There is prompt where it says would you like to move this comment to chat is there any provision of Personal Messaging if i need any help further.